# Fade in and out a div contains video embedHTML in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div and three links when a link is clicked the div is set its innerHTML with an embedHTML of video and i need to cause some effects when the current div video is changed on clicking the link

Example :

```
<a id="Link1" onClick="ChangeVideo(1)">Link1</a>
<a id="Link2" onClick="ChangeVideo(2)">Link2</a>
<a id="Link3" onClick="ChangeVideo(3)">Link3</a>
<div id="CurrVideo"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
//The ArrEmbed is an array that is set on the load of the page::
var ArrEmbed = new Array();
function ChangeVideo(index)
{
   $('#CurrVideo).fadeTo(1000,0.25,function(){
   document.getElementById("CurrVideo").innerHTML = ArrEmbed[index-1];
   });    
    $('#CurrVideo).fadeTo(500,1.25); 
}
</script>
```

The effect is not noticeable and fading with opacity diminshing is not noticed even if the duration time is increased (e.g. 'slow') and when i replace the EmbedHTML with image this code is applicable and the effect of fading is noticed but with the video it is not noticeable so how can i solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance for any try

Note:
The embedHTML differ as it may come from youtube or any server or from my JWPlayer.

Comment: Are you using a javascript framework at all? I'm not familiar with the syntax of this one specifically, but some events would make your code a bit easier! Also, have you tried this with a bunch of browsers, that is important to know.

Comment: i have tried it and the problem now is in the flsh player doesn't feel with the effect so i have solved it by another way but still need to know how can i solve the problem of flsh player animation

Answer (score 0):

I have searched and searched for a solution to this problem because I would like to do something similar with adobe .pdf objects but in short, I have found that there is no way to make this work.

See my SO post on this matter:

[Alternate method of inserting a .PDF file into HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337624/alternate-method-of-inserting-a-pdf-file-into-html-page)

I know thats not the answer you wanted to hear, I was equally disappointed.  The major problem exists because the adobe objects actually render themselves 'on-top' of the HTML as if they were just floating elements that are not connected in any way to your HTML, therefore you cannot manipulate them.

To solve your problem you may look at containing each video in separate `<div>` tags and executing your jQuery function on that div rather than the video object itself.  You will probably lose the fadeIn,fadeOut effect but at least you would be able to `.css({display:'block'})` or `.css({display:'none'})` showing/hiding the video when you wanted to.